# Fix characters in PHP

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Anyone know what this is and how to fix it? â€œThe OMGâ€�

```
<p>After 32 years in its former location, this popular restaurant 
   and bar moved to the bottom of the Avalon Bay Luxury residential building 
   that's just a walk from Angel Stadium. Modern and welcoming, the expansive 
   space is where fans, locals and families gather for upscale twists on classic
   American dishes. Burgers here have a decidedly fun flair like â€œThe OMGâ€� 
   that is a burger surely meant for sharing (with many)--it's so huge that it's 
   served on a 14-inch bun. The restaurant also specializes in seafood with such 
   items as Chilean sea bass, mahi mahi and swordfish. The lounge also serves 
   signature drinks like  the Rally Monkey Martini in tribute to the mascot 
   of the Angels.</p>
```

This seems to a problem because of a function I have to run on the JSON data before decoding it or JSON decoding will fail:

```
function safeJSON_chars($data) {
$aux = str_split($data); 
foreach($aux as $a) { 
    $a1 = urlencode($a); 
    $aa = explode("%", $a1); 
    foreach($aa as $v) { 
        if($v!="") { 
            if(hexdec($v)>127) { 
            $data = str_replace($a,"&#".hexdec($v).";",$data); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
return $data;}
```

Comment: `echo urlencode(htmlentities('â€œThe OMGâ€�'));` not sure if this is what you are looking for. outputs `%26Atilde%3B%26cent%3B%26acirc%3B%82%26not%3B%26Aring%3B%93The+OMG%26Atilde%3B%26cent%3B%26acirc%3B%82%26not%3B%26iuml%3B%26iquest%3B%26frac12%3B`

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem yet?

Comment: $editorial_review = mb_convert_encoding($value["editorial_review"], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'); did not help.

Comment: page is set to utf-8 and my web browser is too. not sure what the data is set to, its from from an API.

Comment: It seems that these characters are url encoded already, missed that because firefox didn't show them in view selection source, they are: &#226;&#128;&#156;The OMG&#226;&#128;&#157;. Now I need to work with these. Maybe try doing a dechex() then check the utf8 encoding?

Answer (score 6):

**Have a look at this page**

[Unicode-friendly PHP and MySQL](http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/)

On this page you will find an easy and clear explaination of UTF-8 encoding and how to apply this in your websites along with some practical examples.

You will also need to make sure that your files are saved using UTF-8 encoding (without BOM).

Comment: Most complete answer imho. Please note you also need to save your files using UTF8 (without BOM). Because typing special chars in an ISO file and trying to display it as UTF8 will break as well ;-)

Comment: @Capsule: Thanks! That's right, I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can set the page charset:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: page is set to utf-8 and my web browser is too. not sure what the data is set to, its from from an API.

Answer (score 1):

Is your character-set set to Latin1 perhaps? Try using UTF-8 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: page is set to utf-8 and my web browser is too. not sure what the data is set to, its from from an API.

Answer (score 1):

Those would be microsoft quotes in Unicode utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful:
[str_replace() equivalent for Multi-byte string like UTF-8](http://snipress.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/str_replace-equivalent-for-multi-byte-string-like-utf-8/)

Then use it like this:

```
$replace = array("&Scaron;");
$replace = array("&scaron;");
$search = array("Š"); 
$search = array("š");  

$queryText= mb_replace($search, $replace, $queryText);
```

Comment: That is a stupid function - the name pretends it is a replacement for str_replace, but it isn't.

Comment: `str_replace` is already binary safe, which means that you can work with any multi-byte string without any problems