# str_replace gives wrong result

Tags: php, unicode, hex, rtf, str-replace

I got data like this: "ӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ".
hexing this data to this: d398d086d2a2d292d2aed2b0d29ad3a8d2ba
then adding "\'" for *.rtf format: \'d3\'8d\'86\'2a\'d2\'2d\'ae\'2b\'d2\'ad\'a8\'2b

and then I must get somethingl ike this: \u1179\'3f\u1240\'3f\u1186\'3f...

but str_replace replaces only slashes Q_Q.

Any suggestions?

here is full code:

```
<?
function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}

function extra($txt) {
    $output_arr = array (
        //
        "\\u1179\\'3f","\\u1240\\'3f","\\u1186\\'3f","\\u1170\\'3f","\\u1198\\'3f","\\u1200\\'3f","\\u1178\\'3f","\\u1256\\'3f","\\u1210\\'3f"
    );

    $input_arr = array (
        // 
        "\\'d3\\'98","\\'d0\\'86","\\'d2\\'a2","\\'d2\\'92","\\'d2\\'ae","\\'d2\\'b0","\\'d2\\'9a","\\'d3\\'a8","\\'d2\\'ba"
    );

    echo "<br>";
    echo "data: ".$txt."<br>";
    $txt = strtohex($txt);
    echo "hex: ".$txt."<br>";
    for ($ii=0; $ii < strlen($txt); $ii++) {
        //
        if (strlen($tm1)<2) {
            //
            $tm1.=substr($txt,$ii,1);
        }
        else
            {
            //
            $ret.="\\'".$tm1;
            $tm1='';
        }

    }
    echo "RET:[".$ret."]<br>";
    $ret = str_replace($input_arr,$output_arr,$ret);
    echo "RETREP:[".$ret."]<br>";
    return $ret;
}

extra("ӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ");
?>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451144/php-multi-byte-str-replace

Comment: @Tom, no. this is not for me, these letters was taken from mysql db. they in unicode(utf8). so I'm trying to compare hexed values and to replace it using rtf spec format.

Comment: mb_str_replace is what you are looking for

Comment: Guys... The string only contains characters [0-9a-f\\'], what would a multi-byte function achieve in such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting wrong results because of "if" logic in "for" loop.
Here is the right one:

```
for ($ii=0; $ii < strlen($txt); $ii++) {
    //
    if (strlen($tm1)<2) {
        //
        $tm1.=substr($txt,$ii,1);
    }
    if (strlen($tm1)==2) {
        //
        $ret.="\\'".$tm1;
        $tm1='';
    }

}
```

In old version (question) this thing was skipping every third char of the main string. So now it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I see no immediate problem with your code, other than the fact that the string you use as an example contains none of the sequences in `$input_arr`. I added manually `\'d3\'8d` to that list, and the replacement worked correctly, so this might be the source of your problem.

You appear to be converting an UTF-8 to an ASCII representation that escapes Unicode characters as `\u{code}\'3f`, so you might be able to leverage [the `utf8tohtml` function described in this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#96648), which escapes characters in the `&#{code};` format.

Comment: I already found my mistake and solved the problem. :) oh, and thanks for utf8tohtml.