# str_replace with Arabic character

Tags: php

i try to replace some arabic caractere with another symbole
some arbic caractere is replaced but one of this caractere it not replaced 
first i try to split the word 
second try to replace the caractere
the caractere is َ ً ٍ ِ ْ ُ all this are replaced but the problem is with this caractere ّ
**strong text**
this is the code

```
   $spelling="";

function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {

if ($l > 0) {

$ret = array();

$len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {

$ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");

}
return $ret;
}
return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

if(isset($_POST['txt_word'])){

 $spelling = implode("  ", str_split_unicode($_POST['txt_word']));

}


 $search  = array('ّّ ','ً ','ٍ ','ٌ ','ُ ','َ ','ِ ','ْ ');

$replace = array('0/','/0','/0','/0','/','/','/','0');

$subject= str_replace($search, $replace,  $spelling);

$alphabet=array('أ','ا','ب','ت','ث','ج','ح','خ','د','ذ','ر','ز','س','ش','س','ص','ط','ظ','ع','غ','ف','ق','ل','م','ن','ه','و','ي','لا','ة','إ','ئ','ؤ','ك','ى','ء');

$rep=array('','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');

$res=str_replace($alphabet,$rep,$subject);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Multi Byte str\_replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451144/php-multi-byte-str-replace)

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` should be able to handle Unicode characters If it does not, you are probably not passing it Unicode.

Make sure that you are handling Unicode strings all the way through from the displayed website to the PHP script. See this article for further information: [„Unicode-friendly PHP and MySQL“](http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://www.php.net/preg_replace on similar cases.

```
$replace = array(
   '/ä/u'=>'a',
   '/p/u'=>'r',
);

$patterns = array_keys($replace);
$replacements = array_values($replace);

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```