# substr_replace() when used with special charactors (äöå) replaces with a?

Tags: php, special-characters, str-replace

I am able to replace special characters, however when it happens it replaces them with "?".
I basically want to replace the ä in this example with an underscore.

UPDATE:
 I do not want to replace all ä's, I only want to replace the first ä

```
$answer = "päivä";
$answer = substr_replace($answer, '_', 2, 1);
echo $answer;
```

Output:
p�_ivä

Thanks :)

Comment: substr_replace() works on __byte offset and length__ not on character offset and length.... if you're working with a multibyte charset, one character is not one byte

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451144/php-multi-byte-str-replace. It might give you some clues.

Comment: Hi, I do not want to replace all ä's, I only want to replace the first ä

Comment: What about [this](https://3v4l.org/DZA9Z)?

Comment: Yeah thanks that helped! I still wanted to be able to select the letter so I added a line of code https://3v4l.org/SUN9H @Uchiha